# WPF Collections synchronization misbehavior

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

In my WPF/MVVM application I make heavy use of collections which are bound through DataBinding to my views. These shall be sync-ed through

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Collection, _collectionLock);
```

placed in the constructor, so that when I receive an update notification I should not get any exception.
This is the code which performs the collection update:

```
private void MyCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    var newItem = new ItemViewModel(item as DataTypes.Item);
                    newItem.PropertyChanged += itemsCollection_PropertyChanged;

                    Collection.Add(newItem);
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    Collection.Remove(Collection.First(x => x.Name == (item as DataTypes.Item).Name));
                }
                break;

            //Reset = Clear
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                Collection.Clear();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Problem is that even if it is synchronized as shown, I still receive the following Exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll.
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

I tried different ways but still getting this error; the only way is to update the collection through a Dispatcher call but it seems to me this would be superfluous due to the Collection being synced.

EDIT: it seems that I'm getting the Exception even when invoked from a Dispatcher call, and that's seems an even worse behavior to me.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Collection.Add(newItem);
}));
```

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Collection.Add(newItem));
Can you try this? Same for .Remove and .Clear of Collection

Comment: I tried in the meanwhile, and it still crashes with the same exception; see my edit. It's kinda odd..

Comment: Can you post how exaclty you invoked the dispatcher-thread?

Comment: See my latest edit, that applies to all the calls.

Comment: So in your xaml you have something like <SomeControl ItemsSource={Binding Collection} /> right? What class is "Collection"?

Comment: I checked out my code. The binding it's actually done on a getter property which however returns the same collection but filtered by a field. Collection is a List<MyItem>

Comment: get a reference to the dispatcher in your view model like this:

`public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  Dispatcher dispatcher;
  public MyViewModel()
  {
   dispatcher = App.Current.Dispatcher;
  }
}`

and then use it: 
`dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> { //code }));`

Comment: @Socket2104: have you tried using an ObservableCollection<MyItem> instead of a List?

Comment: I observed the same behavior with both the types; now I reverted back to ObservableCollection (as it was originally) but no luck